# Too many duplicate IP with same MAC address in output of arp-scan

Tags: networking

My company network is very unstable. It takes so much time to ping to gateway about 50ms or higher. I did some troubleshoot to find out the cause. I have to try arp-scan when network is unstable and see many duplicate IP with same MAC address. This is a section of output:

```
192.168.6.1 00:1d:xx:xx:xx:xx   xxx Corp.
192.168.6.1 **e8:9a:xx:xx:xx:xx**   Quanta Computer Inc. (DUP: 2)
192.168.6.4 0a:55:xx:xx:xx:xx   (Unknown)
192.168.6.5 0a:55:xx:xx:xx:xx   (Unknown)
192.168.6.10    64:66:xx:xx:xx:xx   (Unknown)
192.168.6.29    50:e5:xx:xx:xx:xx   GIGA-BYTE TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.
192.168.6.31    08:9e:xx:xx:xx:xx   (Unknown)
192.168.6.38    30:65:xx:xx:xx:xx   (Unknown)
192.168.6.38    **e8:9a:xx:xx:xx:xx**   Quanta Computer Inc. (DUP: 2)
192.168.6.47    18:03:xx:xx:xx:xx   Dell Inc
192.168.6.62    00:26:xx:xx:xx:xx   Wistron Corporation
192.168.6.77    2a:91:xx:xx:xx:xx   (Unknown)
192.168.6.78    e8:9a:xx:xx:xx:xx   Quanta Computer Inc.
192.168.6.95    40:16:xx:xx:xx:xx   (Unknown)
192.168.6.95    **e8:9a:xx:xx:xx:xx**   Quanta Computer Inc. (DUP: 2)
192.168.6.110   40:16:xx:xx:xx:xx   (Unknown)
```

My gateway is 192.168.6.1. All duplicate has same MAC address (MAC in **). I think it is a forged MAC because I try to find the machine and shutdown it but my network is still unstable. I think it is a starting point to find out what is happening but I am stucking to continue.

Comment: That's certainly interesting.  Do you know what piece of equipment the Quanta box is?

Comment: In normal state of network, I also scan and find out many devices Quanta Computer Inc. I think the attacked device is Quanta Computer Inc but the number of devices are not little. Do you have any idea to find out what device behind forged MAC **e8:9a:xx:xx:xx:xx**

Comment: If you have a manageable switch, yes, it's trivial - get the switch to show you the MAC address table, and you'll see what port that MAC address is known on.

Comment: Our switchs are unmanaged. I am trying to find out via tools :(

Comment: I'm afraid this is one very good reason not to used unmanaged switches any more - you have no tools at all when things go pear-shaped.  Managed switches are now sufficiently reasonably-priced that any decent business should be able to afford them; it may be time to tell management to stump up for a decent network, or live with the 50ms turnaround.

Comment: we had a plan to imporve network with managed switch. It will take a week for establishment. For a while, we also need to find out the cause and a solution.

Comment: OK, I got your idea. I will try it. The Business only improve infrastructure when they see the problem disturb them. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17287/discussion-between-luke-nguyen-and-madhatter).

Comment: With an unmanaged switch there is really only two ways you can narrow problematic equipment down to a specific port. Either you look at the LEDs to correlate flashing of one of the LEDs with traffic to/from the problematic MAC. Or you unplug cables until you have tracked down the problem. But you can unplug a cable and reconnect it immediately through a managed switch, then you'll quickly know on which side of that managed switch the problem is. You only need two ports, so a Linux box bridging between two interfaces could be used as a managed switch for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraints you've outlined in your comments above, all you can really do is leave an ARPping running to that MAC address, and unplug (then reconnect) the network leads from the switchgear, one-by-one, until the ARPping stops.

When the ARPping stops, that's the lead with the guilty piece of kit on the end. Yes, this is highly-disruptive to network operations; the business will have to make a decision as to whether persisting with the problem is more or less disruptive than finding it.

And yes, we are all familiar with business management who won't invest in improvements until there's a Dreadful Problem - and they then want it fixed at once.  I'm sorry you've got such a set of managers; they're idiots.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like what round expect I'd someone was doing ARP spoofing to intercept traffic.  That can also cause some instability depending how the intercepting machine behaves, and whether it can keep up with the traffic.

The MAC address will be related to a particular hardware manufacturer, which might help you track it down, but also it can be faked.

Does the suspect MAC address correspond to any non duplicate ARP records?  Does it appear in periods where the network is not unstable?

If someone is using ARP spoofing to sniff traffic, then they are redirecting that traffic via themselves.  Quite likely their connection is very busy and you can pick it out from the flashing lights on your switch, and follow the cable to them.

Comment: When network is unstable. I observe switch flash light. I see all port light continuous blink. I am possible to focus a specific port.

Comment: I see duplicated IP when network is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy **[arptables](http://linux.die.net/man/8/arptables)** on legitimate boxes to filter arp trafic while you are looking for managed switches deployment.